# Cabal install pcre-light on windows. Extra-include-dirs/extra-lib-dirs not working

Tags: haskell, mingw, cabal

I'm using MinGW+MSYS,

I've added extra-include-dirs, extra-lib-dirs, but nothing seems to be helping cabal find the pcre library. Here are some command lines I've tried, and some sample output below it.

```
cabal install pcre-light --extra-include-dirs='C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\include' --extra-lib-dirs='C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib'
cabal install pcre-light --extra-include-dirs='/C/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/include' --extra-lib-dirs='/C/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/lib'
cabal install pcre-light --extra-include-dirs="/C/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/include" --extra-lib-dirs="/C/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/lib"
```

and I keep getting something along these lines:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at C:\Users\user\src\DBSite\dbsite\.cabal-sandbox
Configuring pcre-light-0.4.0.3...
Failed to install pcre-light-0.4.0.3
Last 10 lines of the build log ( C:\Users\user\src\DBSite\dbsite\.cabal-sandbox\logs\pcre-light-0.4.0.3.log ):
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pcre-light-0.4.0.3-9072\pcre-light-0.4.0.3\dist\dist-sandbox-6710ae14\setup\setup.hs, C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pcre-light-0.4.0.3-9072\pcre-light-0.4.0.3\dist\dist-sandbox-6710ae14\setup\Main.o )
Linking C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pcre-light-0.4.0.3-9072\pcre-light-0.4.0.3\dist/dist-sandbox-6710ae14\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring pcre-light-0.4.0.3...
setup.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: pcre
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
pcre-light-0.4.0.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: Run cabal install with `-v3`, it will print the exact command which is failing. Your include/lib dirs contain spaces, so you may need to quote the entire thing: `cabal install pcre-light "--extra-include-dirs=..."`

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll do that and get back here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really need to answer this problem since I suppose that a lot of people suffered from it. Just be clear for my system specification: Windows 7 64-bit, GHC 7.8.3 64-bit, cabal 1.20.0.3

Possible failure reasons:

#### 1. missing C library

#### 2.32-bit library is incompatible with 64-bit GHC.

### You need to do:

#### 1. A kind company airesoft built pcre with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. Go to http://www.airesoft.co.uk/pcre to download the pcre you want or click http://www.airesoft.co.uk/files/pcre/pcre-8.33.zip to download 8.33. (Can somebody upload it to sourceforge?)

#### 2. Change the file name pcre3.lib to pcre.lib and pcreposix3.lib to pcreposix.lib(I suppose this file is actually not needed but just in case.) I copied the file instead renaming it directly, but I think both ways are fine.

#### 3. Depending 32 or 64-bit GHC, you need to specify the extra library and include. pcre-light requires pcre.h and pcre.lib. On my machine I just run

cabal install pcre-light --extra-lib-dirs=E:\\DOWNLOAD\\pcre-8.33\\lib\\x64 --extra-include-dirs=E:\\DOWNLOAD\\pcre-8.33\\inc

If your GHC is 32-bit you just remove the \\x64 in the above command

#### 4. Of course, you need to add pcre3.dll into your system library path. I just copied it to C:\Windows\System32 directory. (I am not sure whether you need to rename it to pcre.dll, keep both in case. Make sure you choose the right file since 32-bit dll will crash on 64-bit machine and vice versa) Open your GHCi you should be able to import Text.Regex.PCRE.Light and try to invoke some functions.

I will try to merge the files into the pcre-light package inside it if possible.
Good luck

Answer (score 2):

It should be a lot easier to install `pcre-light` nowadays on Windows if you do the following:

- Install [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/) and install the `pcre` package by running `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-pcre` (for 32-bit Windows) or `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pcre` (for 64-bit Windows).
- Make sure you have GHC 7.10.3 or later. (Earlier versions come bundled with an outdated version of MinGW that wouldn't work well with MSYS2.)
- Make sure you install [`pcre-light-0.4.0.4`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcre-light-0.4.0.4) or later with `cabal install pcre-light-0.4.0.4`. (Earlier versions wont't configure the extra dependencies automatically, which would require you to manually set `--extra-lib-dirs` and `--extra-include-dirs` flags.)

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the very same problem. I downloaded Haskell-Platform 32bit (version 7.10 at the time of writing), and unzipped `pcre-7.0-lib.zip` which i got from the [gnuwin project on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/pcre/7.0/)

```
cabal install pcre-light --extra-include-dirs=C:\temp\pcre-7.0-lib\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\temp\pcre-7.0-lib\lib
```

So, i did *no* escaping of the backslashes and i also did not quote the string. I did also not rename the contents in the zipfile.

I should mention that it was executed from a [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder)-shell which adds a few unix tools to the path. With a plain cmd.exe, i get a warning because Cygwin or MinGW/MSYS is required.